# Cocoa: Animating content

Tags: cocoa, animation

I am porting an iPhone app to Cocoa and I'm finding that concepts are different.  For instance on the iPhone if I want to animate my custom activity indicator, I construct it as follows

```
-(void)makeActivityIndicator
{
    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s1.png"]; 
    UIImage *s1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str1];

    NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s2.png"];
    UIImage *s2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str2];

    NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s3.png"];
    UIImage *s3 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str3];

    NSString *str4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s4.png"];
    UIImage *s4 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str4];

    NSString *str5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s5.png"];
    UIImage *s5 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str5];

    NSString *str6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s6.png"];
    UIImage *s6 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str6];

    NSString *str7 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s7.png"];
    UIImage *s7 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str7];

    NSString *str8 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s8.png"];
    UIImage *s8 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str8];

    NSString *str9 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s9.png"];
    UIImage *s9 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str9];

    NSString *str10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s10.png"];
    UIImage *s10 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str10];

    NSString *str11= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s11.png"];
    UIImage *s11 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str11];

    NSString *str12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"s12.png"];
    UIImage *s12 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str12];

    activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:s1];

    activityImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         s1,
                                         s2,
                                         s3,
                                         s4,
                                         s5,
                                         s6,
                                         s7,
                                         s8,
                                         s9,
                                         s10,
                                         s11,
                                         s12,
                                         nil];
    [s12 release];
    [s11 release];
    [s10 release];
    [s9 release];
    [s8 release];
    [s7 release];
    [s6 release];
    [s5 release];
    [s4 release];
    [s3 release];
    [s2 release];
    [s1 release];

    activityImageView.animationDuration = 1.0;  
    activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(386 - 36, 512 - 36, 72, 72);
}
```

and then I can display it with:

```
[mainView addSubview:activityImageView];
[activityImageView startAnimating];
```

and stop it with

```
[activityImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

Are there similar concepts for Cocoa?  Will you point to the place in which doc where this is spelled out?

Dan

Comment: Start by creating a loop to DRY up your code. Then look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/AnimationGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html